# Would someone explain the meaning of some notation relating to the definition of Weak Measurability?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, lebesgue-measure

I have been independently reading the text $Lebesgue \ Integration$ by Soo Bong Chae, but have gone down a bit of a rabbit hole trying to learn more about measurability beyond the scope of this book and have become lost in some of the notation and definitions. I have tried to distill many questions down to a few key ones which I hope will clarify a lot for me once answered, so I appreciate your indulgence.

So, I have the following definition:

For a real Banach space $V$, and a function $f: [0,T] → V$, $f$ is said to be weakly measurable if $t → \langle v,f(t)\rangle$ is measurable for all $v \, \epsilon \, V^*.$

First, what does the $\langle \,, \rangle$ notation denote? Typically I understand this to mean an inner product, but if $V$ is only assumed to be a Banach space, then I suppose this isn't the case here. It seems like I am assumed to know what it means, but I am afraid I do not, and have not been able to deduce its meaning from contextual clues.

I have also seen the more compact notation $f \, \epsilon$ $C([0,T];V)$, which I think I am right to believe is just $f$ as defined previously, only now with the addition that $f$ is a continuous such function.

However in trying to then understand subsequent examples given, I have encountered the collections $C^n([0,T];C^n([0,T]))$, and $C^n([0,T]^2)$, and I have no confidence that I am understanding these objects correctly. The first I believe is just, n$^{th}$-continuously differentiable functions on $[0,T]$ to the collection of n$^{th}$-continuously differentiable functions on $[0,T]$. But after much searching, I can only guess at the second. I have thought perhaps the Cartesian product, but am disinclined to think I am correct in this interpretation, because then I could not imagine any connection between the two.

In any case I am grateful for any light that can be shed on the subject, and hope these questions are not too ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people use the notation $ \langle v, x \rangle$ for the value $v(x)$ of $v$ at $x$. $v:V \to F$ is a continuous linear map and $x \in V$ ($F$ being the scalar field).

Your guesses for $C([0,T];V), C^{n}([0,T])$ etc are all correct.

Incidentally,  $ \langle v, x \rangle$ becomes an actual inner product in the case of Hilbert spaces when the dual space is identified with the space itself using Riesz Theorem.

Comment: Ah, well that is gratifying. Thank you very much.

So just to make certain I understand you correctly, with $t → \langle v,f(t)\rangle$ in mind, I should understand $\langle v,f(t)\rangle$ as something like the composition $v(f(t))$, where $v$ and $f$ are both from $V$, but $v$ additionally comes from the subset of linear functionals in $V$, $V*$, which I understand is the dual-space of $V$?

As for the rest, I am surprised I was correct about $C^n([0,T]^2)$, if only because now I cannot guess at the connection between those. I am running out of characters now, so will have to continue.

Comment: Continuing, it seems to me that $C^n([0,T];C^n([0,T]))$ is quite clear with respect to "where you begin, and where you end up" in the sense of domains and codomains. You begin in C$^n$ functions over $[0,T]$, and you end up back there, so I could equivalently write $v$: $C^n([0,T]) → C^n([0,T])$. Yet, for $C^n([0,T]^2)$, all I can see that as is $v$: $C^n([0,T]$x$[0,T]) →$ ... and I don't know where I "end up".

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but as it stands, I do not see how these collections are connected, and would continue to be grateful for any further insight.

Comment: @ElliotM98 $C^{n}([0,T]^{2})$ is usually either real valued or complex valued continuous functions on $[0,T]\times [0,T]$.